# Why does my cout output not appear immediately?

Tags: c++

it does not print the string put in the loop. The program was written with the help of g++, with sys/types.h header file included

```
for(int i=0;i<9;i++)
{
    cout<<"||";
    sleep(1);
}
```

Answer (score 18):

You're not flushing your output.

```
std::cout << "||" << std::flush;
```

Answer (score 10):

What you're likely seeing here is an effect of the output being buffered.  In general the output won't actually be written until `std::endl` is used.

```
for(int i=0;i<9;i++)
{
    // Flushes and adds a newline
    cout<< "||" << endl;
    sleep(1);
}
```

Under the hood `std::endl` is adding a newline character and then using `std::flush` to force the output to the console.  You can use `std::flush` directly to get the same effect

```
for(int i=0;i<9;i++)
{
    cout << "||" << flush;
    sleep(1);
}
```

Comment: Maybe you should precise that endl both add an end of line AND call a flush. An '\n' alone  should be enough most of the time.

Comment: *In general the output won't actually be written **until a new line is printed**.*  .. That is not correct. A newline doesn't give that guarantee. Note that `std::endl` adds a newline to the buffer **and** then flush it.

Comment: The reason std::endl works it adds the end of line stuff (\n for *nix, \r\n for Windows) and an std::flush.  The key part is std::flush, but std::endl certainly works.

Comment: @JaredPar: That is irrelevant, as the output may actually be written even if there is no newline; it all depends on how big the buffer is, and how it is implemented.

Comment: @Nawaz that is why i said "in general" because it is generally true but not always.

Comment: @JaredPar: In this case, "generally true" doesn't make sense, because it is true for any character. I may say *"In general the output won't actually be written **until a vowel or a number is printed**"*. That can be observed to be true as well.

Comment: @Nawaz my current answer uses `std::endl` vs. the phrase "new line".  I stand by the answer as written.  It is in fact generally true.  Yes there are specific cases where the behavior can differ which again is why I said "in general".

Comment: @JaredPar: `std::endl` is not just newline; it is the *flush* thing in it which is doing the job, which you mistakenly think the *newline* thing does. Also, your edited answer is **still misleading**, as it says *"....until std::endl is used"* which is wrong. One may use `std::flush` to force the output, without using `std::endl`.

Comment: Is this compiler-dependent? I don't recall having this issue with MSVC.