# Heavy method call blocks cout

Tags: c++, cout

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why does my cout output not appear immediately?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10554474/why-does-my-cout-output-not-appear-immediately)

I have a very heavy method (it checks if a number is a prime - Euler 3), which blocks `cout`.
How is this possible? This is my code:

```
int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {
    cout << "-----------------------------------------------------------" << endl;
    cout << "isPrime(3): " << ((isPrime(3)) ? "true" : "false") << endl;
    cout << "isPrime(10): " << (isPrime(10) ? "true" : "false") << endl;
    cout << "BLAH";
    cout << "BLAH";
    cout << "BLAH";
    cout << "BLAH";
    cout << "BLAH";
    cout << "BLAH";
    cout << "isPrime(600851475143): " << (isPrime(600851475143.0) ? "true" : "false") << endl; // This one takes very long to complete
    cout << "-----------------------------------------------------------";
}
```

Like this, it outputs:

```
[Session started at 2013-01-19 13:50:12 +0100.]
-----------------------------------------------------------
isPrime(3): false
isPrime(10): false
```

and then stops (for a few minutes). (`isPrime()` is broken, I know!)
If I comment the line with `isPrime(600851475143)` out, it outpus everything except the output of the commented line of course in less than a second.

How is it possible that a very heavy method call blocks output that should already have been written to `cout`?

Comment: There may be some problem in your function `isPrime`. e.g it could be stuck in a loop.

Comment: Nope, the number is just very big (and it's logic is broken, so it runs extra long). I waited a few times for it to complete. @sgar91

Comment: @RaymondChen How should I have found that?

Comment: This is why it is important to set a good title for your question. So that others can find answers more easily. That other person did a bad job, and everybody suffers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`cout` writes to the standard output, which is typically line-buffered.  i.e. the buffer is only flushed to the console when it encounters a newline character or an `endl`, or when you explicitly call `cout.flush()`.

Comment: Thank you! Will accept your answer in 12 minutes!

Answer (score 1):

If you use `cout.flush();` or `cout << endl;`, the output that is pending up until the point of the flush will be printed.

This is due to the fact that cout tries to be efficient in it's usage of I/O calls. Since all of the code runs in one thread, there is no way to add a timeout or something, so if you have a call that takes several minutes, the output will not be processed.

Answer (score 0):

The stream buffers the output, and only writes it to the console when it sees a newline character.